# Exception in constructor - C++

Tags: c++, exception

So, I want to restrict making objects without parameters given in constructor using try-throw-catch. Here's what I've written so far. But it's not working properly, what should I do? No errors, just returns 0.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        Person(int _age)
        {
            age = _age;

            try
            {
                if (age == -1)
                {
                    throw 1;
                }
            }

            catch (int x)
            {
                cout << "You have to specify person's age" << endl;
            }
        }

    private:
        int age = -1;
};

int main(void)
{
    Person a();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Person a();` is a declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning a `Person`. It's not a definition of a variable of type `Person`. You could write `Person a;` or `Person a{};` - those won't compile since `Person` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: The proper of doing this is having the try-catch in the ``main`` function where you're creating a ``Person`` instance. With this, the ``Person`` instance is created even if the age is invalid and the question is, should a ``Person`` object be allowed to have an invalid age?

Comment: Also, even if you say `Person a;`, that won't compile because the default constructor will not have been synthesised, as you have provided a non-default constructor.

Comment: So, the way to solve this problem is to create a default constructor and write the same try-catch-throw construction there, then delete the object and close the program?

Comment: If you don't want the function to be called without parameters do not make a default constructor.

Comment: Your code allows a Person to be created with age -5.  You may want to consider `age` as an *unsigned* integer, since negative ages don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
Person a();
```

A vexing parse. This does not declare a variable and invoke the constructor, it declares function `a` that returns a `Person`.

Solution:

```
Person a;
```

but this sets up problem 2:

There is no default constructor. Specifying `Person(int _age)` defines a non-default constructor and this blocks the compiler from generating a default (parameter-less)  constructor. This is actually a win for you because your stated goal is to not be able to construct a `Person` without parameters.

You cannot

```
Person a;
```

You must

```
Person a(<an int>);
```

This does not prevent a user from

```
Person a(-1);
```

Which makes little sense for [anyone not from Ork.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy) This sets up a great example for use of an exception in a constructor and exposes problem 3:

There are two ways out of a constructor that don't end the program: With a constructed object and by a thrown exception. Both throwing and catching an exception that signals construction has failed in a constructor is unusual because it allows an improperly constructed object to be returned.

So

```
Person(int _age)
{
    age = _age;

    try
    {
        if (age == -1) // probably should reject age < 0
        {
            throw 1;
        }
    }

    catch (int x)
    {
        cout << "You have to specify person's age" << endl;
    }
}
```

Actually causes the problem you are trying to avoid.

Solution:

```
Person(int _age)
{
    age = _age;
    if (age == -1)
    {
        throw 1;
    }
}
```

and in `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    try
    { 
        Person a();
        // use a
        return 0;
    }
    catch (int x)
    {
        cout << "You have to specify person's age" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

There is one big improvement that can be made: Make exceptions meaningful

Throwing 1 contains too little context to be meaningful. You can throw and catch a custom exception, but for something simple like this `std::runtime_error` from `

```
Person(int _age)
{
    if (_age == -1)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("You have to specify person's age");
        // do not new an exception. It's hard to clean up and free the memory
    }
    age = _age; // why assign then test? Save a clock cycle.
}
```

and in `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    try
    { 
        Person a();
        // use a
        return 0;
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) // where possible catch by constant reference
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```